# AJAX Requests memory leak

Tags: javascript, ajax, memory, safari, xmlhttprequest

I am working on some Ajax for a page that polls a app. The app returns a JSON string and the browsers parses it and hands it off to the screen.

As this polling takes place every 500 milliseconds (arbitrary) I notice that the response is coming back to the browser and being added to the resources section of the browser - see attachment[image]. 
My question then is "Is this normal for every response to mount up"? If this app is left for 20 mins that is a hell of a lot of built up items...

Comment: What does "every response to mount up" mean?  Debuggers, when they are active, save a lot of info to help you see what's going on.  That info would not normally be saved if the debugger was not open.

Comment: Mount up means to increase over time... So are you saying that that snippet that you see called userStats is really just an artefact of the debug area? I just see a new one for every response....

Comment: Yes, it's just an artifact of the debugger saving info to help you use it when it's active.  Ajax data should not accumulate on its own if the debugger is not open.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are seeing is an artifact of having the debugger open.  When it's open, it saves lots of information about what is going on.  When the debugger is not open, it is not saving anything.

Ajax results should not accumulate on their own if the debugger is not open.